# Wiring a recessed light fixture

Tags: recessed-lighting

How do I connect 3 black wires, 1 red wire, and 1 piggy-tailed white. I can connect the hot black for the light but I can't get the switch to turn on or off, and I've tried all kinds of combinations trying to connect the red.
How do I post a photo?

Comment: Yes, you asked this before, and we needed more detail to understand the problem.  You did not read the requests for more detail, you did not provide the additional detail by editing that post or commenting.  Please do that instead.   Also I realize you probably won't read this, but **do not try combinations**.  There are many combinations which 'seem to work' but actually create a hazard that will bite someone later.

Comment: Press "edit" in "share edit ..." at the bottom left of your post, then hit the button that looks like a mountain-and-sun in a picture frame, and it will prompt you for the picture to add.